# Is it possible to use to set a parameter in Simulink without running a Matlab script?

Tags: matlab, drop-down-menu, parameter-passing, simulink

When a Simulink model contains a parameter, its value can be set using a script.

> For instance, a constant block could have the value `a`, and the script would then contain the expression `a=2` to set its value.

Is it possible to set the parameter inside the Simulink model, without running a Matlab script?

> For instance, the Simulink model could containa drop-down menu that alows you to set the value of the parameter.

Comment: i don't really understand everything - can you clarify for me, plz? You use simulink model. And change it's parameters. Do you use script from MATLAB? Without opening model itself? Or all this thesis are about GUI?

Comment: I do not think you can easily add a drop-down menu IN simulink. You will have to create another GUI yourself. Try using GUIDE if you are not familiar with GUI in Matlab.

Comment: @oro777 that's wrong. All you need are [**masked subsystems**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/block-masks.html). All other other functions and init parameters you can put into the PreLoad function, so you don't need any external files and can modify everything within the model.

Comment: Additionally, you can look into Simulink Dashboard if you're on R2015. I agree with @thewaywewalk that it's probably cleanest to use masks for this.

Comment: Saying that, without a minimal example provided by you, this question is way to broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions include

- Making your own GUI (see GUIDE)
- Using [masked subsystems](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/block-masks.html)
- Using Simulink Dashboard blocks